# How to retrieve authentication/emailmethods values of a user using Microsoft Graph SDK?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, azure-ad-b2c

I'm retrieving the users from `Azure AD` with the following code. I want to retrieve the `authentication\emailmethods` and the `email address`. I set up the API Permissions as mentioned on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-emailmethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Although I have `authentication` in the query, the API call returns `null` for authentication.

What should I specify in the query to return the value for `authentication\emailmethods`?

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
{
    requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] 
    { 
        "displayName", 
        "id", 
        "givenName", 
        "surName", 
        "streetAddress", 
        "city", 
        "state", 
        "postalCode", 
        "country", 
        "userPrincipalName", 
        "authentication"
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot retrieve authentication details for all users. You need to make a separate call for each user.

```
var result = await graphServiceClient
                   .Users["{user_id}"]
                   .Authentication.EmailMethods.GetAsync();
```

Other requirement is to have `UserAuthenticationMethod.Read.All` [permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-emailmethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

For delegated scenarios where an admin is acting on another user, the administrator needs one of the following Azure AD roles.

- Global Reader
- Authentication Administrator
- Privileged Authentication Administrator

Answer (score 1):

> **Note** that: You have to make two different calls to fetch the users and then another call to fetch the authentication method of the user.

I agree with @*user2250152*, you need to pass **UserID** to fetch the authentication details of a user.

```cs
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Azure.Identity;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        string tenantId = "TenantID";
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string clientSecret = "ClientSecret";
        string userID = "UserID";

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

        var users = await graphClient.Users.GetAsync((requestConfiguration) =>
        {
          requestConfiguration.QueryParameters.Select = new string[] { "displayName", "id", "GivenName", "StreetAddress", "City", "State", "PostalCode", "Country", "UserPrincipalName" };
        });

        foreach (var user in users.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Display Name: {user.DisplayName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"ID: {user.Id}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Given Name: {user.GivenName}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Surname: {user.Surname}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Street Address: {user.StreetAddress}");
            Console.WriteLine($"City: {user.City}");
            Console.WriteLine($"State: {user.State}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Postal Code: {user.PostalCode}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Country: {user.Country}");
            Console.WriteLine($"User Principal Name: {user.UserPrincipalName}");
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }

        var graphClient1 = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);
        var emailMethods = await graphClient1.Users[userID].Authentication.EmailMethods.GetAsync();
        foreach (var emailMethod in emailMethods.Value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email name", emailMethod.EmailAddress);
            Console.WriteLine("Id", emailMethod.Id);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

**References:**

[List emailMethods - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/authentication-list-emailmethods?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)

[List users - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-a-user-account-using-a-sign-in-name)